# Product of an exponential function of IDD variables

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

if $x_i$ are IID  continuous random variables, with $E[x_i]=μ$, is the following correct?

$E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n(1+⍺\space x_i)^i\right] =
\prod_{i=1}^nE\left[(1+⍺\space x_i)^i\right] = 
\prod_{i=1}^n(1+⍺\space E\left[x_i\right])^i =
(1+⍺\space μ)^n$

thanks!

Comment: You haven't told us much about the pdf/pmf of $x_i$.  Can we assume $x_i$ is continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  This is not correct.  You cannot take the expectation inside of the exponent term.  Here, you'd have to use the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) and calculate:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{i=1}^{n}E\left[(1+\alpha x_{i})^{i}\right] & = & \prod_{i=1}^{n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+\alpha x_{i})^{i}f_{X_i}(x_i)dx_i
\end{eqnarray*}

where $f_{X{_i}}(x_i)$ is the common probability density function of each $x_i$